# Symfony2 Jobeet tutorial day 3 error invalid mapping

Tags: php, symfony, mapping, symfony-2.1, jobeet

When I generate bundle entities with code

```
php app/console doctrine:generate:entities EnsJobeetBundle
```

I'm getting this error

> [Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\MappingException]
>   Invalid mapping file 'Ens.JobeetBundle.Entity.Affiliate.orm.yml' for class 'Ens\JobeetBundle\Entity\Affiliate'.

This is Affiliate.orm.yml file:

```
 Ens\JobeetBundle\Entity\Affiliate:
  type: entity
  table: affiliate
  id:
    id:
      type: integer
      generator: { strategy: AUTO }
  fields:
    url:
      type: string
      length: 255
    email:
      type: string
      length: 255
      unique: true
    token:
      type: string
      length: 255
    created_at:
      type: datetime
  oneToMany:
    category_affiliates:
      targetEntity: CategoryAffiliate
      mappedBy: affiliate
  lifecycleCallbacks:
    prePersist: [ setCreatedAtValue ]
```

Comment: You should indent your yml file correctly

Comment: where is that tutorial?(url)

Comment: http://www.ens.ro/2012/03/21/jobeet-tutorial-with-symfony2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try opening the file in a text editor, and replacing " " with " " globally.

My colleague was having the exact same issue on the same file, and it turns out the problem was that the file was using something other than spaces as spaces. `file(1)` showed that the file was a UTF-8 Unicode text rather than plain ASCII.

I believe this may be caused by the source of the copy + paste using different space characters.

Comment: Still got the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

This yaml .yml configuration files cannot contain TABs. Only spaces as intendation. That is the problem.