# Namespace doesn't contain mapped entities in Symfony 2

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I've created a new entity in src/Andrei/StatisticsBundle/Entity/Attribute/Value/ButtonVarchar.php. Here is the code for this class:

```
<?php

namespace Andrei\StatisticsBundle\Entity\Attribute\Value;

class ButtonVarchar
{
    protected $value;
}
```

and in src/Andrei/StatisticsBundle/Resources/config/doctrine/ButtonVarchar.yml I defined the following mapping information:

```
Andrei\StatisticsBundle\Entity\Attribute\Value\ButtonVarchar:
    type: entity
    table: button_attribute_value_varchar
    id:
        id:
            type: integer
            generator: { strategy: AUTO }
    fields:
        value: 
            type: string
            length: 255
    manyToOne:
        button:
            targetEntity: Button
            inversedBy: attributeValues
            joinColumn:
                name: button_id
                referencedColumnName: id
```

For some reason when I run php app/console doctrine:generate:entities I get the following error:

```
[RuntimeException] Namespace "Andrei\StatisticsBundle\Entity\Attribute\Value" does not contain any mapped entities.
```

I can't understand why is this happening. Can someone point me to the right direction? Thank you.

Comment: Shouldn't the name of the config file be `ButtonVarchar.orm.yml`?

Comment: That was the problem Michal. Thank you! But for some reason, after renaming I get the following error when running the cli command: Invalid mapping file   Invalid mapping file 'Andrei.StatisticsBundle.Entity.ButtonVarchar.orm.yml' for class 'Andrei\StatisticsBund  
  le\Entity\ButtonVarchar'.

Comment: check this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16624324/symfony2-jobeet-tutorial-day-3-error-invalid-mapping

Comment: I figured out. My filename for db mapping should be named Attribute.Value.ButtonVarchar.orm.yml instead of ButtonVarchar.orm.yml

Answer (score 1):

Did you add your StatisticsBundle to Doctrine config?

eg:

```
doctrine:
  orm:
    auto_mapping: true
    mappings:
         AndreiStatisticsBundle: ~
```

You can see mapping problem in the following link:

https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/675

Comment: But it works for al entities located in Andrei/StatisticsBundle/Entity. The problem appears if I use entities from Andrei\StatisticsBundle\Entity\Attribute\Value

Comment: In my opinion, you don't use Entity from \Attribute\Value directory, just put it into Andrei\StatisticsBundle\Entity. Doctrine maybe parse only from the Entity root.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your entities are separated into fine grained packages. In that case you need to specify `fully qualified namespace` in order for it to work.

```
 targetEntity: Fully\Qualified\Namespace\To\Button
```

Answer (score 0):

It may also help.

This works:

```
MyUniqBundle:Entity
```

This doesn't work:

```
MyUniqBundle/Entity
```